# SQL SERVER - get records based on the earliest date being within a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

Bit of a complicated one for me.

I have a database full of hundreds of thousands of records, many of which are duplicated.

I need to get all records within the last year but making sure every instance of that record is within the last year, e.g. if a record is duplicated and one is older than a year this shouldnt be included.

So far I have the below...

**Step 1** - find out earliest date for each record

```
SELECT MIN(CreateDate) AS Date, Email FROM Results R
WHERE (R.Email IS NOT NULL AND R.Email <> '')
GROUP BY R.Email
```

I created this as a view and called it **EarliestInteraction**

**Step 2** - grab all within the last year

**Note** - so I need records within the last year but they also need to be in a log table also. So all records within the last year that are also present in some log tables.

So far I have done this...

```
SELECT * FROM EarliestInteraction ECI
WHERE ( CAST(ECI.Date AS DATE) >= CAST(GETDATE() - 365 AS DATE) )
AND (

    EXISTS (
        SELECT Id FROM LOG1 R
        WHERE Source = 'LOGGED'
        AND R.Email = ECI.Email
    )

    OR

    EXISTS (
        SELECT Id FROM LOG2 R WHERE (R.Email IS NOT NULL AND R.Email <> '')
        AND R.Email = ECI.Email
            AND R.EventType IN (
            'LOGGED'
    ))
)
```

My question is, is this a good way of doing this and accurate?

Or am I missing something that would bring back earlier duplicates...

Any thoughts on if this is accurate or achieves the brief would be great.

Comment: Sample data would really help.  What do you mean by a duplicated record?

Comment: duplicated becuase the results table would have two records with the same email address

Answer (score 0):

You want records where there is no record on the same email address before this year:

```
select r.*
from results r
where not exists (select 1
                  from results r2
                  where r2.email = r.email and
                        r2.created_date < dateadd(year, -1, getdate())
                 );
```

Comment: I use SELECT 1 combinate with exists also, however is this proven select 1 is faster than select  * in this scenario?

Comment: @PawelCzapski No it isn't faster. In exists it doesn't matter at all. You can even put in 1/0 and it works just fine. That is because EXISTS checks for the existence of rows, it doesn't care about columns at all.

Comment: @SeanLange , thnx, it does make sense!

Comment: Does this mean my way is incorrect or just too elaborate

Comment: @MatthewStott . . . Your method seems unnecessarily complex.  I don't know if it is correct.